# How to register an autofac decorator for a generic object for CQRS

Tags: c#, generics, autofac, cqrs, autofac-configuration

is the implementations of CQRS:

```
public interface IQuery<TResult> {}

public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, TResult>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> HandleAsync(TQuery query);
}

public interface IQueryDispatcher
{
    Task<TResult> DispatchAsync<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query)
        where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>;
}

public class QueryDispatcher : IQueryDispatcher
{
    private readonly IComponentContext resolver;

    public QueryDispatcher(IComponentContext resolver)
    {
        if (resolver == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resolver));
        }

        this.resolver = resolver;
    }

    public async Task<TResult> DispatchAsync<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query) 
        where TQuery : IQuery<TResult>
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query));
        }

        var handler = resolver.Resolve<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>();
        return await handler.HandleAsync(query);
    }
}
```

And I want to create the generic query:

```
public class GetEntitiesQuery<TEntity> : IQuery<IQueryable<TEntity>>
    where TEntity : Entity
{
}

public class GetEntitiesQueryHandler<TEntity> : IQueryHandler<GetEntitiesQuery<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>>
    where TEntity : Entity
{
    // this code ... 
}
```

I'm trying to register a generic class as follows:

```
            builder.RegisterType<QueryDispatcher>().As<IQueryDispatcher>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
            .As(type => type.GetInterfaces()
                .Where(interfaceType => interfaceType.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)))
                .Select(interfaceType => new KeyedService("QueryHandler", interfaceType)))
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

And throw error IQueryHandler has not been registered

Is this possible with Autofac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Lots in common with [Issue registering generic types with Autofac in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131910/issue-registering-generic-types-with-autofac-in-asp-net-core/)*

There's no decorators in the code you show.

The error you get is expected as you register your handlers by *keying* them - with the `KeyedService` class. If you want your code to work, you have 2 solutions.

The best option is to not key your services since there's no reason - again, only looking at the code you included - to key your services. You can register them without *keying* them this way:

```cs
builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblies)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The other option would be to instruct Autofac you're looking for a *keyed* service when you resolve the `IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>` since that's how you registered them. To do so, you'd have to modify your `QueryDispatcher` code to:

```cs
var handler = resolver.ResolveKeyed<IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResult>>("QueryHandler");
```

Please not the key passed to the `ResolveKeyed` method matches the one used in the registration code. I don't know why you'd choose the second option, but it's possible.

I assume you got a bit confused with [decorators](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html). Using them requires you to key your services so you can them decorate services that have been *keyed*. Please have another look at [the relevant documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html).

*Edit after Edwok's comment*

For the generic `GetEntitiesQueryHandler<TEntity>` case, I'd say you have to register it as an [open-generic component](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components):

```cs
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(GenericEntitiesQueryHandler<>))
    .As(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>));
```

Comment: Don't working both solutions. Maybe is the GetEntitiesQueryHandler<TEntity> and GetEntitiesQuery<TEntity> 'half-closed' generic component, tried to register decorators, not worked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509729/registering-half-closed-generic-component

Comment: How to with Autofac?